# How to get telepsychiatry in Germany?

Tags: germany, medical

I consider this an expat question since I am an expat and I am looking for important information in a foreign country I don’t know that well.

Germany already has telemedicine services. There are certain apps where you can have a doctor’s appointment and talk to a doctor in an app.

I have not seen a single German telepsychiatry service, and I believe relatively confidently there is none.

However, there is a [rule](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/prescription-medicine-abroad/prescriptions/indexamp_en.htm) that prescriptions within the EU are valid in all EU countries.

Is it possible to receive telepsychiatry from a different EU country?

Answer (score 3):

> I have not seen a single German telepsychiatry service, […]

Oh yes there are.
Traditionally done by telephone, a growing number of physicians are providing their services by video conference, too.

In Germany, all practicing doctors *have* to be in network, the *Kassenärztliche Vereinigung*.
There are 17 regional networks (North Rhine-Westphalia has two).
Their websites feature (a link to) a physician search form.

For example for the state of Lower Saxony, at [physician information Lower Saxony](https://www.arztauskunft-niedersachsen.de/) you will select

- *Fachgebiet* (specialized in) → *Psychotherapie* (psychotherapy, and possibly others)
- *Besonderheiten* (features) → *Videosprechstunde* (video consultation)
- (and probably also) *Fremdsprachen* (foreign languages) → *Englisch* (English)

To find your state’s search form, look at the [Federal Physician Association](https://www.bundesaerztekammer.de/arztsuche)’s site.
The search form’s texts vary widely, some apparently do not even provide a facility to search for *Videosprechstunde*.

> Is it possible to receive telepsychiatry from a different EU country?

You have to appear in person once every quarter year at the doctor’s office and get your health insurance card (the EHIC) read for billing purposes.